# Twig rendering of a mapped objects

Tags: symfony, object, for-loop, twig, one-to-many

I am spinning my wheel to render an object in a twig template. I have 3 entities user >> customer >> account each one mapped to the next with a bi-directionnal one-to-many relationship. I want to fetch all accounts for a specific customer using this controller

```
//...
public function showAction($customerref)
{
 $customer=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeCustomerBundle:Customer')
->find($customerref);
$accounts = $customer->getAccounts();
return $this->render('mytemplate.html.twig', array('accounts'=>$accounts));
}
```

I try to retrieve the information related to the "accounts" object in twig using

```
{% for account in accounts %}
{{ account.id }}
{{ account.number}}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the error "Notice: undefined index:customer". I cannot make sense of this error. When does the "customer" index need to be defined? This is what I have when I dump the "accounts" object.

```
PersistentCollection {#1061 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: Customer {#1060 ▼
    -id: 11
    -name: "nameofthecustomer"
    +user: User {#947 ▼
      -id: 1
      -username: "tom"
      #customers: PersistentCollection {#968 ▶}
    }
    #accounts: PersistentCollection {#1061}
  }
  -association: array:15 [ …15]
  -em: EntityManager {#151 …10}
  -backRefFieldName: "customer"
  -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#948 …}
  -isDirty: false
  -initialized: false
  -coll: ArrayCollection {#1062 ▼
    -_elements: []
  }
}
```

Could anyone give me some guidance on why I get this error? I have used a similar code many times (e.g. to display all customer for one specific user and it worked perfectly well)? Thanks.

Comment: $customer->$this->getDoctrine() should be $customer = $this->getDoctrine() and array('accounts=>$accounts) should be array('accounts'=>$accounts).  When you hear hoofs, think horses, not zebras unless you happen to live in Africa.

Comment: I left some typos indeed (i just corrected them). I happen to have found the solution. I had issues with the way my entities were mapped. This is where I found some useful tips http://obtao.com/blog/symfony2-issues-you-do-not-understand/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left some typos indeed (i just corrected them). I happen to have found the solution. I had issues with the way my entities were mapped. This is where I found some useful tips http://obtao.com/blog/symfony2-issues-you-do-not-understand/